# How to reliably detect color emoji support in browsers

Tags: javascript, browser, emoji

Example of emojis being used: https://slikts.github.io/js-equality-game/

I've set up an image fallback for the emojis, and I'm detecing emoji support using the library [detect-emoji-support](https://github.com/danalloway/detect-emoji-support), but the detection seems to return a false positive when the target system has a partial emoji support, so some emojis end up being monochrome and it doesn't look right.

I've noticed that GitHub in the same system uses image fallbacks for emojis, so there presumably should be a more reliable way to detect support, but what is it?